# Does anyone recognize the characters written on this home shrine?

Tags: meaning, characters, character-identification, traditional-characters, classical-chinese

So far I can read most of the characters on this picture, except 1 character.

- The characters on the center is: 忠義 (zhong1yi4 - Tiong-gī), which
  means: **Loyalty** and is related to the story of [the three
  brothers](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%A1%83%E5%9C%92%E4%B8%89%E7%B5%90%E7%BE%A9). (Thanks to Question Overflow)
- The characters on the left is: 千秋羕 **[x]** 振乾坤.
- The characters on the right is: 萬古桃園喜永存.

Does anyone can read the character mark as **[x]** on the left side? I tried to google like "萬古桃園喜永存", or "萬古桃園喜永存, 千秋羕 ..", but found nothing. Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: Could you maybe post a higher-res image? It's rather difficult to make anything out in the photo you posted.

Comment: 忠義 is read from RTL and [the story of the three brothers](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%A1%83%E5%9C%92%E4%B8%89%E7%B5%90%E7%BE%A9).

Comment: The are some characters covered by the flowers.

Comment: @fefe: Hello, I updated the image, please have a check :)

Comment: @Cocowalla: Hello, I updated the image, please have a check :)

Comment: Hmm, http://i.stack.imgur.com/ isn't blocked any more ... 上聯 (right hand side) is `萬古桃園春永在`, 下聯 (left hand side) is `千秋華年振乾坤`. 橫批 is just like what QuestionOverflow has said, `忠義`.

Comment: @Stan: Thanks, but what does it means? I tried to Google Translate it but it's incomprehensible.. I tried to separate it into a single character to get the original meaning of each character but I can't construct the sentence.

Comment: 萬古(for a very long time) 桃園(the place where ["the story of the three brothers"](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%A1%83%E5%9C%92%E4%B8%89%E7%B5%90%E7%BE%A9) happened) 春(spring) 永在(lasts forever); 千秋(for a very long time) 華年(youth) 振(be the leading actors of) 乾坤(heaven and earth). I think it needs a little knowledge of Chinese culture to understand it well ... However this couplet isn't a good example for learning, because it hasn't followed all the strict rules for couplets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I got: 万古XXX永存，千秋XX振乾坤。 A picture with higher resolution would be helpful for a complete answer.

Comment: @agripop: Wow thanks, please wait for the higher-res image because I have to ask it again to my daughter-in-law. :)

Comment: @agripop: Hello, I updated the image. Please have a check :)

Comment: Looks like 万古桃园喜永存, 千秋羕x振乾坤 to me...

Comment: @user58955 [春](http://images.gg-art.com/dictionary/dcontent.php?word=%B4%BA&sub1.x=0&sub1.y=0) and [年](http://images.gg-art.com/dictionary/dcontent.php?word=%C4%EA&sub1.x=0&sub1.y=0) are written in typical cursive script. "存" looks more similar to [在](http://images.gg-art.com/dictionary/dcontent.php?word=%D4%DA&sub1.x=0&sub1.y=0), but I'm not sure either.